# How to use the continue conversation node in bot framework composer (.NET)?

Tags: botframework

[Microsoft documentation for the ContinueCOnversation class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/599sV.png)

As I found from the documentations the "continue conversation" node in bot framework composer is probably intended to continue a conversation from a later point.

I couldn't figure out how to use it properly.
[Here, I am using the "get conversation reference" node to store the conversation reference in a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjelv.png)

[And here i am using the "continue conversation" node to start the conversation from where I used the "get conversation reference" node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gek9V.png)

Error:

[This is the error I am getting in bot framework emulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGIA.png)

I was expecting the bot to start the conversation flow from the node where the "get conversation reference" node is used to store the conversation reference.

Is it supposed to do that? Or how should I go about implementing this?